# How to find the time to failure of a component using mean failure time

Tags: distributions, quality-control

Is there a way to find the time it will take a component to fail if we know the average failure time.

For example a bulb has a mean failure time of 100 hours but is working even after 200 hours. Can i say at what time it will fail?

I dont have any others statistics like distribution etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What time it will fail will be a random variable, so you can't say what time it will fail.

You may be able to say something about the *distribution* of the time to failure, including its expectation, quantiles, etc, under certain assumptions.

A common assumption for lifetimes of very simple devices with a single main point of failure (the filament in the case of an old incandescent bulb for example) is to assume the lifetime is approximately exponential.

This is an approximation that is occasionally reasonable; however if you don't have a good reason to assume it, you may be in risky territory. Many devices don't behave like that.

Comment: The Weibull distribution also models failure times quite well.

Comment: @Tavrock There are many distributions used for failure times (including the Weibull) but if you use one that has two or more parameters, you won't be able to work out the distribution from the mean failure time alone